# Initializing interface in FragmentActivity

Tags: java, android, interface, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

I'm building a custom interface but I've a problem to initialize it in my FragmentActivity.
This is my log:

```
Process: com.robertot.timereport, PID: 25334
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.robertot.timereport.interfaces.InterfaceUpdateUISummary.onUpdateUIPostExecute(it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.internal.CardArrayAdapter)' on a null object reference
```

I'm trying to initialize my custom interface in onAttachFragment() method, but I think that is not correct...

This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
{
    InterfaceUpdateUISummary updateUI;

    @Override
    public void onAttachFragment(android.app.Fragment fragment) {
        super.onAttachFragment(fragment);
        Activity activity = (Activity) this;
        updateUI = (InterfaceUpdateUISummary) activity;
    }

    //...

    new SelectDataSummary_Async(updateUI).execute();

}
```

This is my second class (AsyncTask):

```
public class SelectDataSummary_Async extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, CardArrayAdapter>
{
    InterfaceUpdateUISummary updateUI;

    public SelectDataSummary_Async(InterfaceUpdateUISummary updateUI)
    {
        this.updateUI = updateUI;
    }

    //...
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(CardArrayAdapter adapt)
    {
        updateUI.onUpdateUIPostExecute(adapt);  //CRASH HERE
    }
}
```

EDIT:

This is the class that implements the interface:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements InterfaceUpdateUISummary 
{
    //...

    @Override
    public void onUpdateUIPostExecute(CardArrayAdapter adapt)
    {
        listView.setAdapter(adapt);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement it in your class not having an instance of it.

**solution:**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements InterfaceUpdateUISummary
```

implements `InterfaceUpdateUISummary` and will generate all the method for the contract.

```
new SelectDataSummary_Async(this).execute();
```

`this` will get the instance of the `InterfaceUpdateUISummary` in your class.

**you need to delete this**

```
 updateUI = (InterfaceUpdateUISummary) activity;
```

it will return null because Activity does not inherit `InterfaceUpdateUISummary`

Comment: Thanks for reply! Ok, but I've a question: InterfaceUpdateUISummary was implemented in other class that extends Fragment...
Simply, in my asynctask I would call updateUI to execute the method in my fragment! :) Does works your solution? Thanks!

Comment: @user3449772 you only need one class that implements the InterfaceUpdateUISummary so other fragments will be comunicated not just 1

Comment: Sorry, I'm uncleared but I edited the main post. Simply, from MainActivity I would execute the asynctask and call the method in the interface to set adapter in MyFragment...